# Why isn't my image being served in react from my local server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image, src

I'm just trying to use a URL in my front end react code, that leads me to an image inside of my Images folder in my node.js server, except it doesn't show up on the front end, it's just blank. I'm baffled right now. I had it working for a split second but for some reason the images just vanished all together when I started shifting things around in various folders. But I have the most basic file / folder structure:

On the front end:

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div>

      {/* submit an image */}


        <img src={"http://<MyIPAddress>:8080/Images/filler image 1 w300.jpg"} id="image-one" style={{width:'100%'}}></img>

     
    </div>
  );
}
```

and my file structure on my node server is simply this:

test-react-server/Images/filler image 1 w300.jpg

the test-react-server folder is the most root level with the server.js file:

test-react-server/server.js

Images is just a folder inside of the root folder, just like you would see the public folder or src folder. I'm totally stumped of why this could be happening. If you could help pin point it I would greatly appreciate that.

I've tried various things, making sure the URL is correct copying via relative path. Tried writing in %20 in the spaces. Tried writing the image and front end src url without spaces. Played with img width and height. Nothing worked. My image remains blank and empty.

Note: currently not using express, only node.js. No alt image or broken image is being displayed, it's just empty and invisible on my front end.

Comment: can you access your image directly by hitting the address in the browser?

Comment: Nope, I tried that and it's not working, and I'm not sure why it's not being served. I'm just totally stumped right now.

Comment: How are you serving the image? are you using relative path without the `path` library?

Comment: I just stored the image in a folder called Images on my node.js folder, I thought it's accessible by using a URL instead of getting the binary Data or buffer, e.g. http:<ip address>:8080/Images/myimagename.jpg, wouldn't this be accessible from the front end if I used it in src? I'm not sending any buffer or base64 strings in a response or anything. Nor am I using fs.readFile(). I'm not using the path library or relative path library either, just trying to access the image with a URL and the image name. Maybe I should try it though and send it in the response.

Comment: Your  nodejs server does not serve any files by default.  So, unless you have specific code to serve that image from your nodejs server, it won't do it.  You will have to show us your server code if you want further help with the server side of things.

Comment: Oh okay, I didn't know that. I will write the code then. I just assumed a front end sending a request to a static folder would be read. Okay thanks alot that makes sense. I guess I got tripped up because there was a fluke and it did show a photo, but then it went crashing down and now isn't served. I understand now.